# karplus-strong guitar pluck using c# and naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm just trying use naudio to implement guitar plucked string using Karplus-Strong algorithm according http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos126/assignments/guitar.html.

Now I have this for Read method:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int samples = (int)(SamplingRate / Frequency);

    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
    {
        var arr = _ringBuffer.ToArray();
        buffer[i] = (byte)((short)((Math.Pow(2, 15) - 1) * arr[i]) & 0x00ff);
    }
    Tic();
    return samples;
}
```

and this for Tic method:

```
private void Tic()
{
    var newLastValue = ENERGY_DECAY_FACTOR * ((1 / 2) * (_ringBuffer.Dequeue() + _ringBuffer.Peek()));
    _ringBuffer.Enqueue((float)newLastValue);

}
```

And that sound which I can hear is really no guitar sound. It is like metallic something :). Is there some way to do this better? What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're truncating 16 bit samples into 8 bit ones (can't see what WaveFormat you're using). I'd recommend creating a class that inherits from ISampleProvider, allowing you to provide floating point samples (where 1.0f is full scale) instead.

Also you're completely ignoring the count method of the Read function. That indicates how many bytes are required. For ISampleProvider it is the number of samples.

Comment: No, I used `new WaveFormat();` which creates a new PCM 44.1KHz stereo 16bit format according naudio. Now, I've got class which inherits from WaveStream, so you recommend to you use ISampleProvider instead? I'll try... And count should be used instead samples `(SamplingRate/Frequency)` in my code?

Comment: But in your loop you are writing to every byte, which is 8 bits. If you want to make 16 bit audio you'd have to convert 16 bit samples into two bytes. Also I suspect your algorithm makes mono audio not stereo